# Python error in Test Azure Environment but not in Dev Azure environment

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, sqlalchemy

I have a python durable function that gathers employees from an API (~13000) and loads then into a Microsoft SQL database. I have a dev subscription with a vpn and a subnet that connects to our on premise dev environment, and a test subscription with a vpn and a subnet that connects to our on premise test environment. In dev the function app works perfectly, but in the test environment I am encountering some strange behavior.

Here is the bit of code that is behaving differently between the environments:

```
    edw_credentials = LoadEDW[0]["edw_credentials"]
    workers = LoadEDW[1]["workers"]
    workers_df = pd.DataFrame(workers)
    workers_df = workers_df.replace("NaN", None)

    user = edw_credentials["user"]
    password = edw_credentials["password"]
    host = edw_credentials["host"]
    db_name = edw_credentials["db_name"]
    driver = edw_credentials["driver"]

    connection_string = (
        f"Driver={driver};Server={host};Database={db_name};Uid={user};Pwd={password}"
    )
    connection_url = URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
    )

    engine = create_engine(connection_url, fast_executemany=True, echo=False)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    try:
        with Session.begin():
            workers_df.to_sql(
                con=engine,
                schema="adp",
                name="stg_hr_workers",
                index=False,
                if_exists="append",
                chunksize=1000,
            )
        return {
            "status": 200,
            "worker_count": len(workers_df),
            "message": "All workers uploaded",
        }
    except Exception as er:
        properties = {"custom_dimensions": {"app": "ADP"}}
        logger.exception(
            f"Unknown error loading workers to Database. \n\n\
            ERROR: {str(er)}. \n\n\
            TRACEBACK: {traceback.format_exc()}",
            extra=properties
        )
        payload = {"status": 500, "worker_count": None, "message": str(er)}
        teams_notification(status=payload, params=LoadEDW[0])
        raise er
```

In the dev environment this code runs, and returns the message with status 200, the number of employees that have been uploaded to the SQL database, and the all's clear message.

In the test environment it gets an error in this block:

Message: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

However even though the error is present it still loads all of the employees into the database. I have been running it on a timer trigger throughout the entire weekend, 3 times a day, and this same behavior has been present for all runs.

Is there something I should be checking in the networking? Is there actually something going on with my code that could be causing a difference between the two environments? It seems unlikely that the code has a bug as it has never produced this error in the dev environment, only in the test environment.

update #1: this error is not reproducible on local, it only occurs while hosted in the azure test environment.